# use search to get matching list of files

Tags: python

I am using following function of a Class to find out if every .csv has corresponding .csv.meta in the given directory.
I am getting "None " for file which are just .csv and hexadecimal code for .csv.meta.

```
Result
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1bb4300>
None 
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xbd6378>
```

This is code

```
def validate_files(self,filelist):
    try:
       local_meta_file_list = []
       local_csv_file_list = []

    # Validate each files and see if they are pairing properly based on the pattern *.csv and *.csv.meta
       for tmp_file_str in filelist:
           csv_match = re.search(self.vprefix_pattern + '([0-9]+)' + self.vcsv_file_postfix_pattern + '$' , tmp_file_str)
           if csv_match:
              local_csv_file_list.append(csv_match.group())
              meta_file_match_pattern=self.vprefix_pattern + csv_match.group(1) + self.vmeta_file_postfix_pattern
              tmp_meta_file = [os.path.basename(s) for s in filelist if meta_file_match_pattern in s]
              local_meta_file_list.extend(tmp_meta_file)
    except Exception, e:
       print e
       self.m_logger.error("Error: Validate File Process thrown exception " + str(e))
       sys.exit(1)

    return local_csv_file_list, local_meta_file_list
```

These are file names.

```
  File Names 
rp_package.1406728501.csv.meta
rp_package.1406728501.csv
rp_package.1402573701.csv.meta
rp_package.1402573701.csv
rp_package.1428870707.csv
rp_package.1428870707.meta
```

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: using fnmatch or glob might be easier

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what results you're getting and how they differ from your expecations? I don't understand what you mean when you say: "I am getting `None` for file which are just .csv and hexadecimal code for .csv.meta." Also, can you show what the prefix and postfix patterns are?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to find `.csv` files which have corresponding `.csv.meta` files, then I don’t think you need to use regular expressions for filtering them. We can filter the file list for those with the `.csv` extension, then filter that list further for files whose name, plus `.meta`, appears in the file list.

Here’s a simple example:

```
myList = [
    'rp_package.1406728501.csv.meta',
    'rp_package.1406728501.csv',
    'rp_package.1402573701.csv.meta',
    'rp_package.1402573701.csv',
    'rp_package.1428870707.csv',
    'rp_package.1428870707.meta',
]

def validate_files(file_list):
    loc_csv_list  = filter(lambda x: x[-3:].lower() == 'csv', file_list)
    loc_meta_list = filter(lambda c: '%s.meta' % c in file_list, loc_csv_list)
    return loc_csv_list, loc_meta_list

print validate_files(myList)
```

If there may be CSV files that don’t conform to the `rp_package` format, and need to be excluded, then we can initially filter the file list using the regex. Here’s an example (swap out the regex parameters as necessary):

```
import re

vprefix_pattern           = 'rp_package.'
vcsv_file_postfix_pattern = '.csv'
regex_str                 = vprefix_pattern + '[0-9]+' + vcsv_file_postfix_pattern

def validate_files(file_list):
    csv_list      = filter(lambda x: re.search(regex_str, x), file_list)
    loc_csv_list  = filter(lambda x: x[-3:].lower() == 'csv', csv_list)
    loc_meta_list = filter(lambda c: '%s.meta' % c in file_list, loc_csv_list)
    return loc_csv_list, loc_meta_list

print validate_files(myList)
```